# Modal not opening on dropdown select event in laravel blade

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-4

In my laravel application, I have a dropdown with three options inside a form.

I'm loading the form options via DB through my controller.

```
{{ Form::select('roles', $roles , $userRole,array('class' => 'form-control txt_txt','id'=>'chgRole')) }}
```

This will basically render something like this,

```
<select class="form-control txt_txt" id="chgRole" name="roles">
<option value="Admin">Admin</option>
<option value="Regional Admin">Regional Admin</option>
<option value="User" selected="selected">User</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to display a modal with a message when a user selects the `'Admin'` option from the dropdown.

This is what I have done so far...

```
<script>
 jQuery("#chgRole").on("change", function() {
   var sOptionVal = jQuery(this).val();
   if (/modal/i.test(sOptionVal)) {
     var $selectedOption = jQuery(sOptionVal);
     $selectedOption.modal('show');
   }
 });
</script>

<div id="Admin" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button> 
                <h4 class="modal-title">Role is changing to Admin</h4>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-body info">
                <p>Message 
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer addHEIGHT">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But it's not opening up the modal or not even showing any error in the console either...

Comment: id is always fetched using `#` and then id attribute. e.g. `#Admin` set your dropdown option value to `#Admin` and viceversa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Hassan mentioned in a comment you need to pass # to fetch an ID

Since you are loading the option values from the database I would suggest to do the following.

Modal

```
<div id="Admin" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button> 
                <h4 class="modal-title">Role is changing to Admin</h4>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-body info">
                <p>Message 
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer addHEIGHT">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And change your JQuery to this

```
<script>
    $("#chgRole").on("change", function() {
    var sOptionVal =$(this).val();
    if(sOptionVal=='Admin'){
            $( '#Admin' ).modal('show');
    }
    });
</script>
```

And make sure to include

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```